# What is the highest total starting sum of ability modifier bonuses?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

Baseline data:

Standard point-buy system, 20 points
Calculations before racial modifiers

Example:

STR - 5 points = 14, +2
DEX - 5 points = 14, +2
CON - 5 points = 14, +2
INT - 5 points = 14, +2
WIS - 0 points = 10, +0
CHA - 0 points = 10, +0

Total Points = 20
Array = 14, 14, 14, 14, 10, 10
Sum of Modifiers = +8

Is the highest available sum of modifiers +8?

Other arrays I've found that yield +8:
16,12,12,12,12,12
14,14,14,14,12,8

Are there any more that yield +8?
Are there any arrays that yield greater?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why is this important? Are you considering an alternative point buy method?

Comment: Shear mathematical curiosity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR: +8**

The highest sum of base ability *scores* (not modifiers) will avoid anything 14 or greater, since things cost more at 14 than below. So \$14 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 13 + 13 = 79\$ is the highest possible sum total of base ability scores. The sum total of the modifiers from this is +7.

Because of how modifiers are calculated, however, odd scores are to be avoided. Thus leaving things at 12 gives us extra points to boost a few scores to 14 to increase the overall modifier; dropping two scores to 12 allows us to get another 14, which has a lower total base ability scores (\$14 + 14 + 13 + 13 + 12 + 12 = 78\$), but a higher total base ability modifier, of +8.

Moving one of the remaining 13s to 12 does not give us enough for a third 14. To get that, we would have to reduce one of the 12s. That reduces the total modifier, however, and continuing to lower already-low scores to produce an extra score that is higher is a losing battle, since they cost more. The incontinuities of these equations means that you do hit +8 again (e.g. with your single 16 and five 12s scenario), but you will not beat it.

Different point buy values change this significantly, of course. Seeking relatively uniform, all even arrays remains a sound strategy.

Answer (score 5):

### +8

Maximum stat modifier sums by number of buy points:

- 10 points buy: +5
- 15 points buy: +7
- **20 points buy: +8**
- 25 points buy: +10

I recently made a table with all the possible arrays for easiness of my players to build new characters. It included a column with the sum of bonuses which I used as a source for my answer.

You can find here that table shared with [all the possible stat arrays for the Pathfinder Corebook point buy](https://goo.gl/hVyKfu).